# multiple @Qualifier EJB injection

Tags: interface, ejb, multiple-instances, qualifiers

i have 2 EJB implements same interface, i have some qualifier :

```
@java.lang.annotation.Documented
@java.lang.annotation.Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.FIELD})
@javax.inject.Qualifier
public @interface PayEseConnector {

}
```

and

```
@java.lang.annotation.Documented
@java.lang.annotation.Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.FIELD})
@javax.inject.Qualifier
public @interface MetrilioConnector {

}
```

example of EJB:

```
@Stateless
@PayEseConnector
@Local
public class PayEseServiceImpl implements IConnectorService {
```

or

```
@Stateless
@MetrilioConnector
@Local
public class MetrilioServiceImpl implements IConnectorService {
```

i inject one of those into a class:

public class TestResource {

```
@MetrilioConnector
@Inject 
IConnectorService metrilioService;
```

and my error :

Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type IConnectorService with qualifiers @MetrilioConnector
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @MetrilioConnector @Inject com.real.hr.rest.TestResource.metrilioService
  at com.real.hr.rest.TestResource.metrilioService(TestResource.java:0)
WELD-001475: The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
  - Session bean [class com.real.hr.services.MetrilioServiceImpl with qualifiers [@MetrilioConnector @Any]; local interfaces are [IConnectorService],
  - Session bean [class com.real.hr.services.PayEseServiceImpl with qualifiers [@PayEseConnector @Any]; local interfaces are [IConnectorService]

what i am doing wrong?, with one @Qualifier it is working

Answer (score 0):

Finally the example is OK the error was i renamed a package and dependency was still present so you can use this example to make simple Qualifier for EJB implements same interface, normally @Local is not mandatory...